# EF5 - Navigation properties not loading in a reversed engineered code first model

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, navigation-properties

I'm banging my head on the keyboard with this one, basically what I'm trying to do is rather simple.

I reversed engineered an existing database with the EF Power Tools, I did that mostly because the database in question is quite old and missing a lot of foreign keys, or even primary key for that matter. The goal was to be able to add navigation properties to the generated model, mostly to have a cleaner code when querying the model.

Now I have 2 classes `User` and `CostCentre`, mapped to their respective tables `Users` and `CostCentres` with proper primary keys, PK of `Users` is `Username` named `Userid` in `CostCentres`, theoretical relation between those two is 1 to M (one User can have multiple CostCentre).
I added a navigation property to `User` like so

```
public virtual ICollection<CostCentre> CostCentres { get; set; }
```

I'm initializing the list in the default constructor with a simple

```
    public User()
    {
        CostCentres = new List<CostCentre>();
    }
```

To `CostCentre` I added a User property like so

```
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

In the generated `CostCentreMap` class, I mapped the navigation property like so

```
        this.HasRequired(cc => cc.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.CostCentres)
            .HasForeignKey(cc => cc.Userid);
```

Now whenever I query `db.Users` I can't get the property to fill, I know the navigation property kind of work, because when I do

```
db.Users
.Include(u => u.CostCentres);
```

The resulting query does the join properly on the proper columns in each table, however if I do

```
User user = db.Users
.Include("CostCentres")
.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == userName);
```

The property `CostCentres` stays empty.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something quite obvious but for the love of Barnaby Jones, I can't get my hands on what.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "*...the navigation property kind of works...*" mean? Does `db.Users.Include(u => u.CostCentres)` fill the `CostCentres` navigation property or not?

Comment: Well it kind of does work, because EF is able to form the SQL query properly, but it doesn't because `CostCentres` isn't filled.

Comment: @Slauma Just traced the select query to be totally sure, I even executed it, and it does return the expected result set

Comment: What happens when you remove the constructor?

Comment: `Username` is not part of the key and `Userid` is the primary key in `User` and foreign key in `CostCentre`, right? What type does this property have? Is it an `int`?

Comment: @Slauma ah sorry forgot to mention that in the original question, `User`'s PK is Username, in `CostCentre` the FK is UserId, both are strings

Comment: @Jay, sorry missed your comment, if I do remove the constructor, the property simply stays null (edit: null not empty)

Comment: Do the names in `UserId` of the related `CostCentres` in the database *exactly* match with the `Username` in `User`, or are there differences (capital/small letters, leading/trailing blanks, etc.)?

Comment: @Slauma it's an exact match, no dif at all, the traced query confirms that

Comment: Well, that's not really a proof because with default latin collation SQL Server (are you using SQL Server btw?) would ignore case differences in the names, but EF will not when it builds the object graph in memory. Can you run 2 tests (one after each other in the same context): `User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == userName);` and `var costCentres = db.CostCentres.Where(c => c.UserId == userName).ToList()`. 1) Does `costCentres` contain the expected result collection? 2) Is `user.CostCentres` populated now (with the same entities as `costCentres`)?

Comment: @Slauma Yeah I'm using SQLServer (2008 R2), pretty sure the cases are the same in both column, going to try anyway, brb

Comment: @Slauma nope, same result property `CostCentres` is left empty (tried with and without the Include, as I'm in lazy loading), `var costCentres` however does have a single result as expected

Comment: Nasty problem :( Do you have overridden `Equals` and/or `GetHashCode` in one of the entities?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have trailing spaces in your key values (like comparing `'ALFKI'` with `'ALFKI   '`)?

Comment: @Slauma nope, all the entities are reversed engineered, all the modification I have done to it are placed under a tag comment, no override of Equals and GetHashCode at all, they are very simple POCO classes.

Comment: @Pawel yep totally sure, earlier tests shown that

Comment: Urg I just tried to load the symbols for debugging, apparently my workplace network blocks the download ... Lovely